# Multi objective optimization using genetic algorithm

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-computing

I have an objective function `profit = income - expense` . I want to solve it using genetic/evolutionary algorithm (strength pareto SPEA2). Since the algorithm is multi-objective so can I consider the income maximization as one objective and expense minimization as second objective?. I am using SPEA2 matlab code from [YARPIZ](http://yarpiz.com/74/ypea122-spea2). I am not sure whether this approach of breaking objective function is technically correct. Secondly, please also throw some light on how to do both conflicting objective simultaneously. The code in link is written for minimization of objective functions, but I have to minimize one and maximize other objective.

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see if it works?

Comment: sir thanks for response, I did it by breaking, now I am faced with issue  of how to apply constraints in strength pareto algorithm (SPEA2). I have bound constraints that variable is between 0 and 1 ( minimum 0 and maximum 1). Also the sum of decision variable should be 1. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Just define profit as a variable and maximize porfit as your singular objective. In general the objective will depent on multiple variables indirectly and the variables will usually also depend on each other. If this is not the case there are probably much more effective solutions than genetic algorithms.

Comment: sir thanks for response. I will try your suggestion.